# Checking if a certain custom permission is enabled in a Profile

Tags: visualforce, formula, profile, business-logic, custom-permission

Is there a way to programmatically figure out whether a certain custom permission is enabled in User profile?

The problem that I'm trying to solve – is that I need some kind of a flag for a small subset of User profiles that would allow me to build some logic on top of. Let's say, I have a visualforce page, and I want to manage visibility to certain visualforce components on this page, such that the users who have a profile with that flag will not see those components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might make more sense to use a `Hierarchy Custom Setting`, which allows you to use the `$Setup` [global variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm). Note that you will get the most specific applicable instance, which is either for the whole `Organization`, a `Profile`, or a specific `User`.

```
$Setup.MyHierarchySetting__c.SomeField__c
```

You can also access if the running user has a specific `Custom Permission` using the `$Permission` [global variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_permission.htm).

```
$Permission.MyCustomPermission
```

I've used both of the above to great effect, and both are pretty easy to work with.

Comment: Thank you so much, @adrian-larson, this is the information I was looking for